# ECS container routing with an application load balancer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I know application load balancers are new in AWS, and discussions (help) are scarce up-to now.

I have a few api containers (docker) running in EC2 Container Service (ECS). I can take advantage of application load balancers to manage routing on an application level rather than a network level. This is exactly what ECS has lacked up until now.

Getting to the point...

I'm trying to get to a point where the load balancer will detect the *pattern* in the request url and route the request to the correct container, but route the request **without** the pattern included.

For example:

http://elb.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/app1/ping
Should route request '/ping' to the app1 container

http://elb.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/app2/ping
Should route request '/ping' to the app2 container

etc...

Each app has it's own *target group* and corresponding pattern: **/app1***, **/app2***

---

### the problem

I can successfully get the a request to '/app1/ping' to route to the app1 container however the request hits the container as '/app1/ping' (obviously) but I only need '/ping' to hit the container. '/app1' is irrelevant to the container.
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I played around with application load balancer for half a day and realised the same thing. It's not intuitively designed. Keen to hear an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Application Load Balancers do a couple of things very well, but there's an awfull lot they do *not* do. This is true for a lot of AWS services (e.g. SQS just recently, after almost a decade got FIFO support) and you can either love or hate this.

Your use case seems to fit the AWS API Gateway very well, which is a service that can be used to map certain external endpoints to certain internal endpoints (and a lot more...). There's even a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-with-microservices-deployed-on-amazon-ecs/) on the AWS blog about how to use Application Load Balancing with the EC2 Container Service and the API Gateway together.

Comment: I agree, ELB2 has a ways to go in this regard. I also agree that API Gateway is pretty perfect for this scenario, however! The pricing model is per request, so on high throughput api's it's just not cost effective for less than critical applications; especially when we know we can do it cheaper.

Comment: True, the API Gateway is overkill in this scenario and therefore too expensive for the benefit. I prefer to go with an API gateway as separate container that runs in your ECS cluster as well, which can do the routing rules for you. You would get one external ALB that routes to the API gateway container and one or more internal ALB's that route to your services that you want to handle routing for. This is a common [design pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) in microservices architecture.